# How do I modify a particular cell of a pandas DataFrame while iterating?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
                   Name  Age  Quantity  Fee  ... wood  wood flooring yellow zoo
0                 Puppy    2         1  150  ...    0              0      0   0
1                London   24         1    0  ...    0              0      0   0
2              Snowball   20         1  150  ...    0              0      0   0
3                Malibu    5         1  100  ...    0              0      0   0
```

I want the name `Snowball` to update `yellow` to a value of `2` (and so on). I need to iterate through all of them, do some processing and update specific columns. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You could start by giving a look at [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: To expand on yatu's comment, OP you want to essentially select the rows where `Name=Snowball` and then assign `yellow=2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by using

```
df.loc[df['Name']=='Snowball','yellow'] = 2
```

The first parameter of loc is the row indexer, the second one is for selecting the column

Answer (score 3):

To index a particular cell and change its value, use df.loc:

```
df.loc[df.Name == 'Snowball', 'yellow'] = 2
```

To efficiently iterate through all the rows of the data frame, use df.iterrows:

```
values_to_insert_into_yellow_by_name = {'Puppy': 1, 'London': 2, 'Snowball': 2, 'Malibu': 3}
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    name = df.loc[idx, 'Name']
    insert = values_to_insert_into_yellow_by_name[name]
    df.loc[idx, 'yellow'] = insert
```

You can use a dictionary to store values that need to be inserted.

Comment: How can I effectively iterate over all rows?

Comment: @Shamoon why would you need a loop? can you explain by an example in the question please? Thanks